# Summarise a feed and send email in the end of the day

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email, rss

A website I visit everyday provide an RSS and Atom feed for their publications. What I want to do is to find a service where I can put this RSS link and in a specific time of the day, it will send me all the new* posts in my personal email.

* New posts are started from the last one of the previous email.

**Platform:** Online

**Price:** Free

**Support:** Gmail or personal email provider (e.g. myname@mydomain.com)

**Schedule:** Add a specific time of the day that will check the RSS or Atom URL and send the email.

Comment: Did you [Google for 'RSS aggregator'](https://www.google.nl/search?q=rss+aggregator)? Many of these are for aggregating RSS into a program (e.g. Wordpress), but I can imagine you find solutions for your case as well.

Comment: All the RSS aggregators I used was a software which just gathered the RSS items. I am not aware of any one which can mail it to you with a specific schedule. @JanDoggen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I see that @DariuszWoźniak posted an answer to @Tasos question *but* @Tasos seemed to have a problem with using Feedly so I created a recipie using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) which just uses a feeds URL instead of an external service like Feedly. It meets your requirements of being,

- Free
- Online
- Support for all email providers
- Can specify what time of the day you want your emails to come in at

## [RSS Daily Digest](https://ifttt.com/recipes/324264-rss-daily-digest)

[image: RSS Daily Digest]

Comment: Seems great. I added the recipe with a daily digest tomorrow morning. I will check if it works and then choose your answer as your best! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may use Daily Digest feature from [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) and integrate it with [Feedly](http://feedly.com/).

The recipe is as following—

Trigger:

- Feedly: New article from specified category *This Trigger fires every time a new article from a specific category appears on Feedly.*

Action:

- Add to daily digest. *This Action will add an item to your daily digest sent once a day at the time you specify.*

The recipe may be read as:

> If new article from category **Your Category**, then add to daily digest sent to **Your@Email.com** at **Specified Time** .

[image: Feedly integfrated with IFTTT]

You may search for ["feedly daily digest"](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=feedly%20daily%20digest) for already created recipes, or you may create one on your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, Feedly is asking for a monthly subscription to connect it with IFTTT. And I am looking only for free service. However, it was a nice idea to use IFTTT.

Comment: @Tasos: That's interesting, I'm using free Feedly...